# how to create in R a vector automatically which contains all groups to be compared with stat_signif package?

Tags: r

So the problem is, I am making some boxplots with ggplot2 in R. I am using the package stat_signif to display the paired comparisons. To do so, I must create a list of vectors to state with groups have to be compare. If I have 2 set of data is fine:

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(x=group,y= value, fill=group)) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      stat_signif(comparisons = list(c(names[1], names[2]))
```

The problem comes when I have many groups. For example, with 4 groups the list of vectors (d) goes like this:

```
 d <- list(c(names[1],names[3]), c(names[2], names[4]), c(names[1], names[2]), c(names[3], names[4]))

 ggplot(data=data, aes(x=group,y= value, fill=group)) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      stat_signif(comparisons = d)
```

Is there a way to create a automatically a list of vectors with all combination possibles not to write to by hand?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combn` on the groups to get all combinations of size 2. Then pass that to `stat_signif`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

pairs <- combn(as.character(unique(iris$Species)), 2, simplify = FALSE)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_signif(comparisons = pairs)
```